# How to change state only one item and return original when click other

Tags: react-native

I have a dialog like this, i want to change state of each face when i click and if i click on other face, current face return to original, for example when i click **neutral** it show green like this pic , and when i click **satisfied**, the **neutral** face return to grey one and the satisfied show it color, how can i do this in react-native, i know how to change state of each item,and like when click it change color , but when i click other i don't know how efficent way to make current item to original state color, so:

**HOW CAN I MAKE THEM TO ORIGINAL STATE IF CLICK OTHER?**

Thank you a lots

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution would be:

1. crete a state variable that is an array of bool:

   ```
   const[clicked, setClicked] = useState(new Array(3).fill(false))
   ```
2. on face click set to true the index of the face that you want to color:

   ```
   const onClick = (event, index) => {
      let result = [...clicked];
      result= result.map(x => false); // reset previous click
      result[index] = true;
      setClicked(result);
   }
   ```
3. put a condition on html to render colored face/greyed face based on `clicked` current status:

   ```
   {clicked[index] && <ColoredIcon />}
   {!clicked[index] && <GreyedIcon />}
   ```

Comment: Thank for your answers, that is what im looking for

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Have a nice codcing =)